# Docker (in VSCode) not accessing forwarded port (on Linux machines)

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code

I typically work with an application using Docker containers in VSCode. It runs Node and Angular applications.

Suddenly today on my Fedora machine I quit being able to access the forwarded port 3000 from the Node application.  However, port 4200 can still be accessed for the Angular app.  Additionally, the 'follow link using forwarded port' click option doesn't go to a browser window any more either.

I purged the Docker container and even restarted the computer. The Docker container still works as expected on another machine.
Nothing is running on port 3000 on the local machine.

I'm at a loss of what to test next. [I'd even uninstalled VSCode and then reinstalled - but it didn't delete the settings.]

To clarify - I've used this image with Docker in VSCode a couple hundred times (I have a tracker).
The container with node is still working with fresh installs on other machines.
I purged the container using:

```
yes | docker stop $(docker ps -aq) ; 
yes | docker rm $(docker ps -aq); 
yes | docker container prune; 
yes | docker image prune -a;
```

I uninstalled VScode and deleted all settings from VSCode using `rm -rf .config/Code/`
(It seems the remote-containers extension was still installed.)

[The VSCode node example using a remote container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-tutorial) - does work.
However, [locally](git clone  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-try-node) it does not.

Recommendations for error detection or trouble shooting would be helpful.

Doing a `curl localhost:5000` inside VSCode, I can see that node is up and running.

My `docker-compose.yml` hasn't been changed in a year and worked fine until yesterday.

I have also purged and reinstalled Docker to no effect.
I have now replicated this in a Ubuntu virtual machine on the same machine (with a fresh install of Docker and VSCode). Repeated tests on a Windows machine continue to work.

I do see on the ports tab of vscode - it says `forwarding port 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:5000 to localhost:5000` for port 5000 (which doesn't work on Linux but is working on Windows) as opposed to port 0.0.0.0:4200 for Angular (which does work).

Similarly with the answer below - using the above node example from vscode with:

```
const PORT = 3000;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello remote world!\n');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
```

in the provided server.js (a file and a container which I in no way touched) - the connection failed.

Comment: This has nothing to do with VS Code, it does not control network connectivity. Instead, start looking at what changed in your docker-compose.yml, which is where you indicate which guest ports are mapped to which host ports.

Comment: I've been narrowing in on that - but there were no changes to docker-compose.yml - which is what's confusing me

Comment: Then you'll want to start by forming a [mcve] - not for us, but for yourself: clone your data to a new dir, and start weeding until there's so little left that removing anything else stops the problem from manifesting. Almost always in the process of that "prework to posting a good question" you end up finding the problem, but if you don't, you now have the perfect code to put in your post, to work both as proof and as demo code others can use to replicate and help debug.

Comment: I had tried the worked example from VSCode using Node. That failed. The example from VScode failed on a clean install of Node and Docker.

Answer (score 0):

For my particular problem, changing

```
const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
 });
```

in server.js to :

```
app.listen(5000, '127.0.0.1', () => {});
```

fixed the problem.
This had not been changed, nor had docker-compose.yml - so I don't know what was introduced or by whom to break it.